# Category of coherent sheaves on blow-ups or resolution of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, descent

Let $X$ be a scheme and $Y$ a closed subscheme. I would like to know if there is a good relation between the category of coherent sheaves on $X$ and the category of coherent sheaves on the blow-up $\text{Bl}_Y(X)$. This is probably a stretch, but one thing I'd naively hope for is some descent property for cdp-morphisms, or some excision-type property. In a sort of best-case scenario, do we have some sort of descent allowing us to understand the category of coherent sheaves a scheme via the category of coherent sheaves on a resolution of singularities? If it helps the situation, I'm fine studying the corresponding derived categories.

Comment: You have proper descent for IndCoh (which in your setting is just the ind-completion of the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves.) Does that suffice for your purposes?

Comment: @dhy Thanks, I'll look into it!